# Putting a material on a fractured model

Tags: unity, blender, materials

I have a square model that has been fractured using blender's cell fracture.
I also have a material that I want to apply onto the broken pieces.

The only problem is that the material needs to be organized in a certain way so it looks right when I replace it with the broken model.

Scripting-wise i'm using Brackey's tutorial for [destruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgNV0PWVaS8)

**How can I make the material look the same on both the fractured and the unfractured model?**

I also left a picture if it helps.

The one on the left, is the unbroken model with the material. The one on the right is the broken model with all the cells having the same material.

[image: The Picture]

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Planar UV Projection](https://blenderartists.org/t/planar-and-spherical-uv-projections/580138/2).

Answer (score 1):

did you unwrap the model before the cell fracture? if so you should do it after everything else. because normally the cell fracture add-on keeps the original uv's as seen here:

[image]

maybe its also a fbx export issue. personally i use these settings to get the desired result in unity: [image]